# creating case from publisher action

Tags: service-cloud-console

i am new to console ,we are creating a case from Asset publisher action by using a vf page and the case is  created successfully but when a case is created it is going to feed view by default but i need the case to go to detail view..

Comment: screen shots of the flow sequence would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I believe that feed-based layouts go to feed view by default, at least when you are originating in feed view (as you are by using the quick-action). Given that you are calling a VF page, you could include methods in an extension to redirect to open the case in a primary tab (using the [Salesforce Console Integration Toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/)). Then you may find that records open in feed view or detail view, depending on what the user last chose.